# How do I get write-access to Samba share from guest account without setting permissions to `g+w`?

Tags: permissions, samba

I am using Samba (4.15.13-Ubuntu) running on Ubuntu 20.04 to make my home directory shareable so I can access it from my Windows laptop. I have the same username on Windows, but it only seems to connect if guest access is enabled.

I have the following `smb.conf` (comments stripped):

```
[global]
   guest account = myuser
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   hosts deny = ALL
   hosts allow = 10.0.0. 10.100.102. 127.
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = user
   map to guest = Bad User
   encrypt passwords = true
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[myuser]
   path = /home/myuser
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   force user = myuser
```

I can connect and read, but if I want write access, it only works if I have group write access. I can write to files which have `g+w`; I can also create files in directories which have `g+w`, but my umask gives `rw-r--r--` as the default permission, so I cannot then modify the file.

This `smb.conf` is copied from another system I ran using an earlier version of Ubuntu, and I didn't have this problem. I could of course change my umask, but I'd prefer samba to allow access as `myuser` to avoid giving write access where it should not be needed.

Is this a problem due to an "improvement" in recent Samba versions? Can anyone tell me how to get write access without changing umask and giving group write access to everything?

[Note: I have resolved this problem by requiring non-guest access, as per the answer below, but would still like to know how to allow write access as a guest without `g+w` on everything.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on is that you forgot to add `myuser` as a Samba user. So as a result, you're only able to connect as a guest.

Regarding the requirement of changing permissions on the share to `g+w`, I can't explain it at the moment. In my testing, I'm able to successfully connect as a guest without changing the permissions on the share. But the difference is I'm connecting from an Ubuntu client and not a Windows client. So perhaps there's something with a Windows client that is requiring the `g+w`.

The fact that you have `force user = myuser` as a setting should have allowed the Guest user to have write permissions, or at least take on the credentials of `myuser`. But perhaps you would also need to add the following to the share in smb.conf:

```
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

Here's a link on Stack Exchange where it looks like someone was having the same issue: [How to create a Samba share that is writable from Windows without 777 permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206309/how-to-create-a-samba-share-that-is-writable-from-windows-without-777-permission)

---

Anyway, to access a Samba share as a valid user and not a Guest, you also have to add that regular user to the list of valid Samba users.

To see a list of current Samba users, enter the following:

`sudo pdbedit -L -v`

Next, if you already have a regular user on your Ubuntu system such as `myuser`, then skip the next step. If not, create a new user:

`sudo adduser myuser`

Then add `mysuser` as a Samba user:

`sudo smbpasswd -a myuser`

If you run `sudo pdbedit -L -v` again, you will see that `myuser` has been added.

Within your `smb.conf`, delete `guest ok = yes` or change it to `guest ok = no`.

Restart `smbd`:

`sudo systemctl restart smbd`

At this point, you should be able to login to your Samba share as `myuser` with write permissions.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Still don't understand the guest access requiring g+w, though.

Comment: I have got this working, as I said, but I still want someone to tell me how to allow write access as a guest without giving group write to everything. I used to be able to do this, but can't get it to work any more no matter what I try.

Comment: I see that you’ve edited the question title to reflect how to solve the Guest account `g+w` issue. But you’ve already marked this question as answered. So I suggest you edit the question title back to how to get write access for a user account and then create a new question for this other issue. Otherwise you might not get people seeing this question and offering an answer to this specific issue.